# Capnp: Move to previous position in BufferedInputStreamWrapper

Tags: c++, capnproto

I have a binary file with multiple Capnp messages which I want to read. Reading sequentially works well, but I have the use-case, that I want to jump to a previously known position.
The data sequential images with metadata including there timestamp. I would like to have the possibility to jump back and forth (like in a video player).

This is what I have tried:

```cpp
int fd = open(filePath.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
kj::FdInputStream fdStream(fd);
kj::BufferedInputStreamWrapper bufferedStream(fdStream);
for (;;) {
  kj::ArrayPtr<const kj::byte> framePtr = bufferedStream.tryGetReadBuffer();

  if (framePtr != nullptr) {
    capnp::PackedMessageReader message(bufferedStream);
    // This should reset the buffer to the last read message?
    bufferedStream.read((void*)framePtr.begin(), framePtr.size());
    // ...
  }
  else {
    // reset to beginning
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
capnp/serialize.c++:186: failed: expected segmentCount < 512; Message has too many segments
```

I was assuming that `tryGetReadBuffer()` returns the position and size of the next packed message. But then again, how is the BufferedInputStream supposed to know what "a message" is.

**Question**: How can I get position and size of messages and read these messages later on from the BufferedInputStreamWrapper?

**Alternative**: Reading the whole file once, take ownership of the data and save it to a vector. Such as described here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capnproto/Kg_Su1NnPOY). Better solution all along?

Comment: Decided to go with the alternative I posted and it works quite well. But if someone feels like answering the question, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedInputStream` is not seekable. In order to seek backwards, you will need to destroy `bufferedStream` and then seek the underlying file descriptor, e.g. with `lseek()`, then create a new buffered stream.

Note that reading the current position (in order to pass to `lseek()` later to go back) is also tricky if a buffered stream is present, since the buffered stream will have read past the position in order to fill the buffer. You could calculate it by subtracting off the buffer size, e.g.:

```
// Determine current file position, so that we can seek to it later.
off_t messageStartPos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) -
    bufferedStream.tryGetReadBuffer().size();

// Read a message
{
  capnp::PackedMessageReader message(bufferedStream);
  // ... do stuff with `message` ...

  // Note that `message` is destroyed at this }. It's important that this
  // happens before querying the buffered stream again, because
  // PackedMesasgeReader updates the buffer position in its destructor.
}

// Determine the end position of the message (if you need it?).
off_t messageEndPos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) -
    bufferedStream.tryGetReadBuffer().size();
```

---

```
bufferedStream.read((void*)framePtr.begin(), framePtr.size());
```

FWIW, the effect of this line is "advance past the current buffer an on to the next one". You don't want to do this when using `PackedMessageReader`, as it will already have advanced the stream itself. In fact, because `PackedMessageReader` might have already advanced past the current buffer, `framePtr` may now be invalid, and this line might segfault.

---

> **Alternative:** Reading the whole file once, take ownership of the data and save it to a vector. Such as described here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capnproto/Kg_Su1NnPOY). Better solution all along?

If the file fits comfortably in RAM, then reading it upfront is usually fine, and probably a good idea if you expect to be seeking back and forth a lot.

Another option is to `mmap()` it. This makes it appear as if the file is in RAM, but the operating system will actually read in the contents on-demand when you access them.

However, I don't think this will actually simplify the code much. Now you'll be dealing with an `ArrayInputStream` (a subclass of `BufferedInputStream`). To "seek" you would create a new `ArrayInputStream` based on a slice of the buffer starting at the point where you want to start.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation and sorry for the late feedback. So with your help I got it working. I would like to work with PackedMessageReader, thus I had to change the approach a little bit. Turns out 30 GB do not usually fit into RAM ;). I read chuncks of 1GB and save the message positions. Then I use lseek to quickly jump to the last saved frame if I have to load new data. Works quite well.